# Swift UITableViewDelegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview

I created a `ViewController` and added a `TableView` to it using `storyboard`.

I set the Class in `Storyboard` for the `ViewController` to my `NewsFeedViewController` class. I set the delegate for the tableview outlet to self.

```
class NewsFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var newsFeedTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newsFeedTableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =
        newsFeedTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
            "newsFeedIphoneCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as! NewsFeedIphoneTableViewCell

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

}
```

When i run the code none of the delegate methods are triggered. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing assignment of data source.

Try adding

```
newsFeedTableView.dataSource = self
```

as well.

Comment: awesome, helped me a lot!